# Making OpenLDAP FIPS 140-2 Validated

Tags: openssl, openldap, fips

I'm trying to make my LDAP application FIPS 140-2 validated. It uses OpenLDAP, so I think I should first try to make OPENLDAP FIPS 140-2 validated (correct me if i am wrong). Is there any patch that does this for OpenLDAP.C

Can any one provide me some references that will help me do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hardenning LDAP through FIPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829681/hardenning-ldap-through-fips)

Comment: You are not only repeating another question, you are repeating *your own* question.

Comment: Because i want the answer to it. it is more specific than the other one. i want open ldap to be fips compliant, not padl this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLDAP uses OpenSSL. It is *OpenSSL* that you need to comply with FIPS 140-2, if it doesn't already. Nothing to do with OpenLDAP per we at all. Quite possibly this is just a configuration issue.

Comment: I have a fips compiled openssl ready. How should i link it to openldap? So that it uses the openssl-fips library. Is it automatically linked to the openssl-fips library by default or do i need to change any thing in openldap?

Comment: @user1286706 It's platform-dependent, but if OpenSSL is being used as a shared library by OpenLDAP just make sure it uses the right version.

Comment: @EJP - I'm not sure about that. OpenSLDAP does *not* call `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms`, but it *does* call `SSL_library_init`. That means OpenLDAP should call `FIPS_mode_set` if `OPENSSL_FIPS` is defined (and it should probably be guarded on a call to `FIPS_mode`). But I don't see that in call in `libraries/libldap/tls_o.c`.

Comment: @jww Haven't seen the OpenLDAP source code but OP has just marked this as correct, which may mean something. Or not. I'm asking OpenLDAP about this.

Comment: FYI - We have OpenSSL working fine in FIPS mode with SIP. But OpenLDAP does not work. There must be some OpenLDAP config that is above and beyond the OpenSSL config.